# Naming convention for association table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables: Posts and Tags.

A post can have many tags. For an association table that would contain `post_id` and `tag_id`, what should that table be called?

`post_tags` or `posts_tags`?

Also, is it still convention in Rails 4 to have those listed alphabetically? i.e. `tags_posts` would not work?

Comment: `tags_posts` would work - if you defined the join_table option in the association definitions (I wouldn't recommend it though - stick to convention unless you're building this association for legacy data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a `Many to Many Relationship`, and you want to define `HABTM`, than the table name should be `posts_tags`.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```